# Jquery: disable the 'click' event on a checkbox

Tags: jquery

In my current JQuery, I have an event that will either check or uncheck a checkbox if the user clicks on a row in a table. The problem with this is, if the user actually checks the checkbox, the jquery will fire on the checkbox event and either check/uncheck the box, but then the TR event will fire and then undo the checkbox value.

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/radi8/KYvCB/1/

I can disable the checkbox but then if the user tries to select the checkbox, the TR event will not trigger.

What I need is a method to disable the 'click' event of the checkbox but still allow the TR event to fire when the checkbox is selected.

```
var charges = {
    init: function() {
        // get the selected row checkbox
        //$('.charges').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.rowclick tr').click(function() {
            if ($(this).find('td input.charges:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                $(this).find('td input.charges:checkbox').attr("checked", false);
            }
            else {
                $(this).find('td input.charges:checkbox').attr("checked", true);
            }
        });
    }
};
charges.init();
```

Comment: what exactly is wrong with your code? what's the result and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/radi8/KYvCB/1/) you posted seems to work... what exactly is your question??

Comment: JKirchartz: no it's not working, if you click on a checkbox, it will toggle twice

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to check if the `click` event was fired on a `checkbox` or somewhere else. **This needs less ressources than a second event handler for the checkbox with `e.stopPropagation`.**

```
    $('.rowclick tr').click(function(e) {
        if($(e.target).closest('input[type="checkbox"]').length > 0){
            //Chechbox clicked
        }else{
            //Clicked somewhere else (-> your code)
            if ($(this).find('td input.charges:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                $(this).find('td input.charges:checkbox').attr("checked", false);
            }
            else {
                $(this).find('td input.charges:checkbox').attr("checked", true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KYvCB/5/

Comment: What if there is another checkbox outside the table? ;]

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks so much for the help. As always, you guys on this list are the best!

Comment: you're right, my fault... I think this is better:  if($(e.target).is(':checkbox')){
                //Chechbox clicked
            } http://jsfiddle.net/KYvCB/8/

Comment: no problem radi8, glad to help you. And tarmaq: yes, it works in this case. you would have problems if the checkbox had child elements (impossible, i know). However, if it was a div element instead of a checkbox, you also need to check if the target is a child of the div.

Answer (score 2):

you need to stop propagation of the `click` event:

```
var charges = {
    init: function() {
        $('.td input.charges:checkbox').on('click', function (e)
        {
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
        $('.rowclick tr').click(function() {
            if ($(this).find('td input.charges:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                $(this).find('td input.charges:checkbox').attr("checked", false);
            }
            else {
                $(this).find('td input.charges:checkbox').attr("checked", true);
            }
        });
    }
};
charges.init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KYvCB/4/