# Change z-index infinitely in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a bit new to jQuery but I need to write a small custom image rotator.  Basically I will have a small stack of .png images that look like Polaroids.  The rotator will need to pull the top one off, move it to the right, set the Z-index lower than the other two, then move it back over...just like you would if you were looking through a stack of pictures.

Most of this I think I can do, but the problem I'm not quite getting is that I will need to continually swap the Z-index of these 3 images (move top image to right, reset z-index lower than the other two, move back)

In the HTML I have the following:

```
<img src="images/polariod_1.png" width="255" height="260" alt="Singer" class="headerrightgraphic">
<img src="images/polariod_2.png" width="255" height="260" alt="Singer" class="headerrightgraphic">
<img src="images/polariod_3.png" width="255" height="260" alt="Singer" class="headerrightgraphic">
```

Any leads on how I can change the z-index on these in an elegant way without hard coding it over and over?

Comment: You can check [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299583/jquery-disable-the-click-event-on-a-checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the z-index, consider giving all the photos the same z-index and reattaching them to the parent node in the order they need to display. This removes the need for "infinite" z-indexes to get content above and below the photos.

For example if the user can click one to pull it to the top, just re-append it to the parent node:

```
// assuming you have a handle to the element `photoElement`

photoElement.parentNode.appendChild(photoElement);
```

Comment: This might be the best way to go, to reorder them.  I will work on that, thanks!

Comment: I'm going to mark this as my answer although it will take me some time to do it, I think this is the best path.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say to store the values in a global variable in your JS, use the `.data` function in jquery or use some hidden inputs to hold the current z-index.

You could also try and not use z-indexing and maybe manipulate the positioning of the elements (elements 'lower down' in the dom tree will appear on top of others), so maybe move it to the site, prepend it to the first img, and then slide it back into place.

Answer (score 0):

What about to use `display:none;` in the images *behind*, that can't be seen?

Comment: When the image slides to the side, he will want the others to be visible most likely

Comment: Ok, but you can play with 2 visible images!

Comment: Yes i have 3 images and I want all 3 to visible "stacked" on top of one another.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using display:none / block instead of changing the z-index. Z-index image galleries have cause me nothing but trouble in the past.

Here is a snippet I found on google.  [Source](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow)

```
$(function(){
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
  $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
     .next('img').fadeIn()
     .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
  3000);
});
```

Comment: This will not give the OP the effect he desires, he wants it to appear as though he is flipping through a stack of images